# Spring Remember-Me not providing correct user details

Tags: security, spring, jsp, remember-me

I used Spring Security 3.0.5's feature "Remember-Me" and in my jsp pages I tried to access the user's details.

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails, Serializable
```

with a few extra attributes (picture url, full name etc.).
Now if I access those attributes using

```
<sec:authentication property="details.pic"/>
```

after a normal log-in (where the remember me feature doesn't kick in) it all works fine.
However when I close the browser and re-open my secured page, the remember-me feature returns another object instead of the details object.

How can I fix this ?
Or should I treat the two different cases ?

Thank you.

**Later Edit:**
I ended up having this in my jsp:

```
<sec:authorize access="isRememberMe()">
    <c:set var="user" value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.principal}" />
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="isFullyAuthenticated()">
    <c:set var="user" value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.details}" />
</sec:authorize>
```

It does the job but I don't really like the approach..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<sec:authorize access="isRememberMe()">
    <c:set var="user" value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.principal}" />
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="isFullyAuthenticated()">
    <c:set var="user" value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.details}" />
</sec:authorize>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your UserDetailsService.loadByUsername() is getting called.   If it isn't then set a breakpoint in processAutoLoginCookie() (in either PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices or TokenBasedRememberMeServices depending on which one you are using) and step through it to see what is happening.

Comment: loadByUsername it is getting called. The problem is that, instead of having a UserDetailsImpl returned by <sec:authentication property="details"/>, I get an org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails object every time remember-me gets executed..

Comment: I think you want to use <sec:authentication property="principal"/>.  AuthenticationDetails is a different concept from UserDetails.

Comment: I updated the main post with some additional info, you can check it out to see what I've achieved so far